# Filling JCombox with SQLQuery throwing null error

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, nullpointerexception

When i try fill a JComboBox with several Employees Names it throws a null pointer error AFTER inserting several names.

I have several other JCombos using the same method but just this one gives the null error.

Is there something obvious that is wrong with this? There are only 2 employees in the table for now.

Console prints out - java.lang.NullPointerException: null and then the database locks up.

```
try {

        String sql1 = "SELECT Employees.Name FROM Employees ORDER BY Name ASC";
        Connection conn = SQLiteConnection.Connect();
        PreparedStatement pst1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
        pst1.setQueryTimeout(5);
        ResultSet rs = pst1.executeQuery();

        while ((rs != null) && (rs.next())) {

            String name = rs.getString("Name");
            nameCombo.addItem(name);
        }

        pst1.close();
        rs.close();
        conn.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Names : " + e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe one of the values returned by your query is `null`.

Comment: @Jack may be right. Give it a go.

Comment: What line does the NPE points to?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jack

It was pulling a null answer from the Database.